# Identify documents after processing in spaCy pipeline?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I have a lot of documents which are processed through a spaCy pipeline.

As I would like to understand and trace back issues with single documents, I would like to identify the source document after it has been processed (encoding, text fragments, wrong tagging etc).
Right now, the pipeline only accepts a list of texts, so I cannot pass any additional ID into it.

Is there any way to specify a document ID which is preserved after the spaCy pipeline so that in can be identified afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set custom extensions on each doc and pass docs rather than texts to the pipeline:

```py
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import Doc

Doc.set_extension("id", default=-1)


def get_docs_from_remote(nlp, size):
    for i in range(size):
        doc = nlp.make_doc(str(i))  # only tokenization
        doc._.id = i
        yield doc


nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm", disable=["ner", "lemmatizer"])
docs = nlp.pipe(
    get_docs_from_remote(
        nlp,
        size=10,
    ),
)

for doc in docs:
    print(doc._.id, doc.text)
```

Comment: That's neat, thanks!

Comment: `nlp.make_doc` runs the tokenizer but no pipeline components.